# Save ReadableByteChannel as PNG

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have a `ReadableByteChannel` which contains an image (either obtained from an URL or a file). I write the Channel finally into a File with a code like

```
final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outImageName);
fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(imageByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Since it is unclear if the image is a `png` or a `jpeg` or ... I want to make sure and save it as `png`. I know I can use the `ImageIO.write(buffImg, outImageName, "png");`

But somehow this requires that the `buffImg` is a `RenderedImage` which raises the question how to obtain it?

Is there a simpler solution than reading the file from the file system with `ImageIO` and than write it as `png`? Can I convert it directly within the memory?

Plus an additional question: Is there a way to tell `ImageIO` to get rid of the AlphaChannel (=transparent)?

Comment: I would go for (1) - but the major problem I have is that I don't know how to use `ImageIO` without first writing the `OutputStream` to a `File` and than read it from there. I would have preferred to do it without writing and reading - i.e. directly.

Comment: If you can, get the `InputStream` or the underlying `File` or `URL` instead of a `ReadableByteChannel`, as `ImageIO.read(..)` supports all those types as input. If not possible, you can use `Channels.newInputStream(..)` to get an `InputStream` you can pass on to `ImageIO.read(...)`. There's no need to write to a `File` first.

Comment: You can also write back to an `OutputStream` or a writeable `Channel` the same way, without going through a file.

Comment: The idea with `ImageIO.read(Channels.newInputStream(ReadableByteChannel))` did it. I didn't know how to convert the one `Channel` to another. Thx.

Comment: @LeO I added some code to the above comment and posted as an answer + added a part about getting rid of alpha channel + writing to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, I suggest getting the `InputStream` or the underlying `File` or `URL` objects instead of a `ReadableByteChannel`, as `ImageIO.read(..)` supports all those types as input directly.

If not possible, you can use `Channels.newInputStream(..)` to get an `InputStream` from the byte channel, to pass on to `ImageIO.read(...)`. There's no need to write to a file first.

Code:

```
ReadableByteChannel channel = ...; // You already have this
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Channels.newInputStream(channel))
```

To get rid of any unwanted transparency, you could do:

```
BufferedImage opaque = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
Graphics2D g = opaque.createGraphics();
try {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Or any other bg color you like
    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

You can now write the image in PNG format, either to a file or stream:

```
if (!ImageIO.write(opaque, "PNG", new File(outputFile)) {
    // TODO: Handle odd case where the image could not be written
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see that the `ImageIO.write` retuns `true`/`false`. Yeah would make sense... But I'm not sure what to do if it fails. Anyways thx for a complete answer (which I failed to do so ;-) ).

Comment: @LeO Yeah, a lot of people forget that, and wonder why nothing happens...  Anyway, with the above code we know the format ("PNG") is supported, and that the PNG format supports the `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` format (well, at least on an Oracle or standard OpenJDK variant), so you could safely just assert it, or throw an exception there. It should never happen.